# How to handle errors and exceptions in Talend

Tags: java, talend

I am new in talend. I am trying to catch run time errors and exceptions and display meaningful message to the end user, but i am failed to do this. I saw many tutorials they use different pallets. If in one tutorial tLogCatcher is used whereas in other file it is using tAssertCatcher. I tried with both but could not do. With that i am confuse that where i have to write xpath to replace the error or exception with my own message.Can anybody help me that how to catch errors and exceptions and show meaningful messages.Thanks

Comment: Good luck with that, since you want to build an exception catcher arond your talend job. Which would catch the exceptions rephrase them write someting meaninful in the console output / log. If you only care about the logs then you should use a tLogCtacher + tMap with a lookup table -> get the first few characters of the Exception join with the lookup table to get the message you want to provide the user.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the tLogCatcher component to catch any errors or warnings thrown by your Talend job. To output these you can then link this to either a tLogRow component to throw them to the console (and run logs) or out to any output that Talend can connect to such as a flat file, database or even send them in an email with a tSendMail component.

If you wish to change the wording of the messages being thrown and then blindly passed on by the tLogCatcher then you could use a tMap or a tReplace or other similar component to look for your input string (the original error message) and replace it for a message of your choosing before outputting it to either the logs or some other target.